# Vector Sort Algorithm, sort only elements bigger then 0

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, vector

I have to sort a vector of structs. Let's say the struct has two members:

```
Struct game
{
  string name;
  int rating;
};
```

So I have created a **`std::vector<game>` games** and simple sort them by rating.

```
std::sort(games.begin(),games.end(), [](game& info1, game& info2)
{
    return info1.rating > info2.rating;
});
```

Everything is alright so far.
The problem is if all games have rating value 0, they mix. Simply put I have to sort only elements with rating bigger than zero. Let's give you an example:

All games are pushed in the vector by names in alphabetic order and rating 0, when a sort is triggered, the alphabet order gets violated.

Example before sort:

`"A_Game"`, `"B_Game"`, `"C_Game"`, `"E_Game"`, `"G_Game"`, etc. (continue with all next letters)

after sort (all games are with rating 0):

`"G_Game"`, `"S_Game"`, `"P_Game"`, `"M_Game"`, `"L_Game"`, `"I_Game"`, etc.

I need to sort only these games that have rating bigger than 0. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does sorting only elements that are bigger than 0 mean? Are the other elements interleaved randomly among the positive ones?

Comment: If you literally want the zero rated items to remain exactly where they are then that isn't possible without more work. If you want the relative order of the zero rated items to remain unchanged, than that's a stable sort.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`std::stable_sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort) to prevent moving around elements that are not affected by the sorting criteria.

```
std::stable_sort(games.begin(),games.end(), [](game& info1, game& info2)
{
    return info1.rating > info2.rating;
});
```

Answer (score 5):

`std::sort()` is **not** a [***stable*** sorting algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability), i.e., elements with equivalent keys may not preserve the original order between them after being sorted.

---

You can use [`std::stable_sort()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort) instead of `std::sort()`:

```
std::stable_sort(games.begin(),games.end(), [](game& info1, game& info2)
{
    return info1.rating > info2.rating;
});
```

As its name already suggest, `std::stable_sort()` implements a stable sorting algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::stable_sort()`.

However, you can keep using `std::sort()` and make the comparator return `true` for games with the same rating (so the relative order is kept), by changing the condition to

```
return !(info1.rating < info2.rating)
```

Comment: It's up to you, bu i'd say `>=` makes the intention of that logic a little more obvious.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stable_sort` instead of `sort`. This would be the best option for the question.

You can also modify the sort so that when two games have equal rating, sort alphabetically comparing the two names (or any other condition that might come up in the future). It might look like this.

```
std::sort(games.begin(),games.end(), [](game& info1, game& info2)
{
    if (info1.rating == info2.rating)
        return info1.name.compare(info2.name);

    return info1.rating > info2.rating;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::sort` indeed doesn't guarantee any ordering for when elements compare equal. `std::stable_sort` guarantees that the original ordering gets kept if it compares equal. (See the other answers)

When in doubt about the original order, I like to explicitly sort with all of the criteria:

```
std::sort(games.begin(),games.end(), [](game const & info1, game const & info2)
{
    if (info1.rating != info2.rating)
        return info1.rating > info2.rating;

    return info1.name < info2.name;
});
```

In the above, I prefer to use the following pattern

```
if member1 different
    return compare member1
if member2 different
    return compare member2

return compare member<last> OR compare pointers
```

This pattern is easily recognizable and easy extendable when you add extra members.

Ideally, when you want to use this sorting at other places, you make this a function with an unambiguous name. (Don't use `operator<` as this causes confusion, since the game titles could as well be used as a logical way of sorting)